# how to Increase VM disk without reboot on Linux redhat 6.x + LVM

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm, vmware

I increased the second disk in VM machine from the VSphere client GUI as the following:

By right click on the machine --> edit settings --> hard disk2 --> increase the disk from 1G to 2G

Then I checked the current disk sdb usage as the following:

```
 sfdisk –s | grep sdb 
 /dev/sdb:   1048576
```

.

```
 pvs
 PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
 /dev/sda2  rootvg  lvm2 a--    15.88g   4.78g
 /dev/sdb   orahome lvm2 a--  1020.00m 508.00m
```

Then I found the sdb disk as the following:

```
  ls /sys/class/scsi_device/2\:0\:1\:0/device/block/sdb/
```

Now I want to update the sdb disk without reboot by the following commands 
rescan the sdb disk:

```
 echo "1" > "/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:1:0/device/rescan"
 pvresize /dev/sdb
```

Please advise if the rescan command and pvresize are the correct procedure in order to increase the disk – sdb to 2G ,

And if I need to perform some other additional commands? 
Or maybe this is enough?

Comment: that is exactly what you are supposed to do.  there are sometime an utilty name rescan-scsi-bus.sh try for it.

Comment: can you please write your answer , and just wrote what is right, according to your remark , I not need to add any additional steps